# Node JS Правильное использование перевенных Steam Market Price

Tags: node.js, steam

В данный момент пишу бота для стима для продажи вещей, столкнулся с не приятной особенностью, возможно самого Node JS, либо steam api. Практически в начале файла у меня созданы 2 переменные, в которые должна записыватся цена предметов, проверяю наличие записей с помощью `console.log()`, но он отображает записи только в том случае если `console.log()` находится в самой функции, хотя как я уже говорил функция должна лишь менять значение этой переменной. Приложу код:

```js
var mannCoKey = 0;
var refined = 0;

function updatePrices() {
 market.getItemPrice('440', 'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key').then(item => {
  mannCoKey = item.lowest_price.substr(1)*1;
  refined = mannCoKey/33*1;
 });
}

updatePrices();

console.log("Mann Co. Supply Crate Key price: " + mannCoKey);
console.log("Refined Metal price: " + refined);
```

Так не работает.
Работает только в таком случае:

```js
var mannCoKey = 0;
var refined = 0;

function updatePrices() {
 market.getItemPrice('440', 'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key').then(item => {
  mannCoKey = item.lowest_price.substr(1)*1;
  refined = mannCoKey/33*1;
    console.log("Mann Co. Supply Crate Key price: " + mannCoKey);
    console.log("Refined Metal price: " + refined);
 });
}

updatePrices();
```

Такой вариант не подходит, мне же требуется, чтобы функция лишь изменяла переменные.

Comment: `getItemPrice` асинхронная. тебе это о чём-то говорит?

Comment: Если честно, то нет. Можно ли где то об этом почитать?

Comment: в любой статье найденной по ключевым словам `javascript Promise`

Comment: Я вроде разобрался, что такое асинхронность, но я не понимаю как это может влиять на переменные?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 1):

Не буду много вам рассказывать про Promise. Вам лучше почитать об этом, вот вам ссылочка https://learn.javascript.ru/promise
Дело в том что в вашем коде блок кода, который находится в then выполняется позже всех(как раз из-за асинхронности), к этому моменту все console.log которые располагаются после вызова функции updatePrices уже отработали и вывели значения переменных объявленных вверху.
Так как вы написали делать не принято, могу предложить вам альтернативный вариант:

```
function getPrices() {
    return market.getItemPrice('440', 'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key')
        .then((item) => {
            const mannCoKey = item.lowest_price.substr(1) * 1;
            const refined = mannCoKey / 33 * 1;
            return { mannCoKey, refined };
        });
}

getPrices().then(({ mannCoKey, refined }) => {
    console.log("Mann Co. Supply Crate Key price: " + mannCoKey);
    console.log("Refined Metal price: " + refined);
})
```

Кроме того вы можете использовать async/await

```
async function getPrices() {
    const item = await market.getItemPrice('440', 'Mann Co. Supply Crate Key');
    const mannCoKey = item.lowest_price.substr(1) * 1;
    const refined = mannCoKey / 33 * 1;
    return { mannCoKey, refined };
}

(async () => {
    const { mannCoKey, refined } = await getPrices();
    console.log("Mann Co. Supply Crate Key price: " + mannCoKey);
    console.log("Refined Metal price: " + refined);
})();
```